# CentOS Installer make ONE partition

Tags: centos

I have tried to install CentOS 6.4 twice now, and it has messed it up twice. Both times I installed it, it setup my harddrive like this: http://gyazo.com/156ab5539eeac09b6785b211f6482c72. I want EVERYTHING to be on ONE partition, like my server came. At this screen, I have tried use all space, and remove existing Linux : http://www.techotopia.com/images/f/f9/Centos6_installallation_allocate_space.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "Create a custom layout" and just make the partitions yourself. I had to do an install yesterday with the exact configuration, and the custom layout was the only one that worked. Just make a small swap partition and the rest mounted as "/".

Comment: How big swap would you say?

Comment: I have 72GB ram.

Comment: Erm, the norm is "1 1/2 times" physical, but with such a large amount a 4 GB should be enough.

Comment: I did 74GB ram xD. Can I still change it? Or is it not worth it.

Comment: Depends if you just want that 74 GB of swap. Highly depends on the setup of your system.

Comment: Well I mean, swap is used when the server runs out of ram right? If my server is going 74GB over 72GB of ram, I have a different problem...

Comment: Exactly. I'd say you could run without swap but keep a smallish partition so you have a buffer in case something goes wrong.

Comment: @CjSculti imagine a server that actively swaps 74 GB. Do you really want that?

Comment: The "old" norm was two times RAM. But that was, when RAM was expensive and disks were fast compared to RAM-access. Now there is not a "norm" regarding swap any longer. But I would say more than 4 GB is normally nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

You could just fix your existing install.
I.e. move your home data to the root partiton , delete the home partition and extend root to use the home space. Take about 10-20minutes and you should theoretically be able to do it without reboot.

log in as root

backup your `/home` data.: `tar cvzf /home.tgz /home`

unmount home: `umount /home`

Remove or comment out `/home` from `/etc/fstab`: `vi /etc/fstab`

remove vg_data-lv_home lv: `lvremove /dev/vg_data/lv_home`

Restore home:

```
tar xvzf /home.tgz
```

extend / (root fs) : `lvextend -L +860G /dev/vg_data/lv_root`

Resize rootfs: `resize2fs /dev/vg_data/lv_root`

if "resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open  /dev/vg_data/lv_root
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock."

then instead use: 'xfs_growfs /dev/vg_data/lv_root'

Profit!